# Can we use passive gerund like present perfect?

Tags: gerunds, passive-voice

Can we use passive gerund like present perfect i.e action just completed before saying like if I'm fired yesterday then can I say like this "I'm still angry about having been fired".

Comment: "I'm still angry about having been fired" seems like good English. Can you clarify what you are concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can form passive gerunds with "being", and perfect gerunds with "having". Here you're doing both, with "having been". Perfectly natural English.

Comment: Then what's the difference between passive present gerund and passive present perfect gerund I mean when we should use them?

Comment: The "present" gerund is non-specific about time, whereas the "perfect" gerund is specifically in the past (I put "present" and "perfect" in quotes, because they're not actually very good terms for it with gerunds). So if it happened yesterday you can say "about being fired" or "about having been fired", but if somebody's told you you're going to be fired tomorrow, you can only say "about being fired".